# TypeError: require.requireActual is not a function

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, storybook, storyshots

I'm getting an error on my Jest tests:

```
 FAIL  test/storyshots.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: require.requireActual is not a function

      1 | import initStoryshots from "@storybook/addon-storyshots"
      2 | 
    > 3 | initStoryshots({
        | ^
      4 |   configPath: "./storybook",
      5 |   framework: "react-native",
      6 | })

      at Object.load (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/frameworks/react-native/loader.js:23:29)
      at Object.loadFramework [as default] (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/frameworks/frameworkLoader.js:26:19)
      at testStorySnapshots (node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/api/index.js:48:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/storyshots.test.ts:3:1)
```

I'm not using `requireActual` anywhere in my code. It looks like [Storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/search?q=requireActual&unscoped_q=requireActual) does, though.

A Google search turned up only one (since deleted) Stackoverflow question with no answer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Jest deprecated `require.requireActual` a while back and recently [removed it](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/9854) in [version 26](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v26.0.0).

Downgrade to Jest 25 to fix it, or find what package is using `require.requireActual` and have them use `jest.requireActual` instead.

EDIT: [Storybook v6.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.3) includes an update that adds Jest v26 support.

Comment: Got the same error and thank GOD that you figure it out. Mine is now also working with lower version of Jest.

Comment: not working in 6-beta.29 https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10351