# Enzyme, test a react component that uses useContext hook with shallow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

[image]

How do I test my component that uses jest and Enzyme with shallow and a react component that uses useContext hook.

How do I mock "pValue.state.fullLang"?

**src\LanguageSelect.tsx**

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { LanguageContext } from './utils/LanguageHook';


function LanguageSelect() {
    const pValue: any = useContext(LanguageContext);

    return (
        <div className="LanguageSelect" data-test="languageSelect-box">
            <div className="languageArea">{pValue.state.fullLang}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LanguageSelect;
```

**src\LanguageSelect.test.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import LanguageSelect from './LanguageSelect';

test.only('that the LanguageSelect component exists', () => {

    jest.mock('react', () => {
        const ActualReact = require.requireActual('react');
        return {
          ...ActualReact,
          useContext: () => ({ state: { fullLang: 'mocked context' } }),
      };
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<LanguageSelect />)

    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="languageSelect-box"]').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    wrapper.unmount();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing that component in isolation then you can mock `useContext` like this:

```
jest.mock('react', () => {
    const ActualReact = require.requireActual('react');
    return {
      ...ActualReact,
      useContext: () => ({ state: { fullLang: 'mocked context' } }),
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is still not working I will update the question with the git hub repo

Comment: I have added your code to my repo for you to see. Many thanks for the help. Did I put the mock in the correct place?

Comment: You need to put `jest.mock` at the same level as the imports, not inside a test itself..I just tested it on your repos and it works

Comment: Awesome. thanks so much. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Will I need to unmock the function afterwards?

Comment: In case of an error Jest removed `require.requireActual`  in version 26. `jest.requireActual` can be used instead.
[TypeError: require.requireActual is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706963/typeerror-require-requireactual-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score -1):

**To test a React function component that contains local functions but doesn't involve elements and events, you can use Vitest and Enzyme**

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ text }: any) {
  const handleClick = (a: number, b: number) => {
    return a + b;
  };
  return (
    <button>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```